# Suggestions for python function optimization

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization

I have the following function

```
def average_over_neighbours(
    distances: npt.NDArray[np.float32],
    velocities: npt.NDArray[np.float32],
    n_neighbours: int = 3,
    weights: npt.NDArray[np.float32] = np.array([]),
) -> tuple[int, npt.NDArray[np.float32]]:

    in_range = distances < search_range
    neighbours: npt.NDArray[np.int32] = np.nonzero(in_range)[0][
        distances[in_range].argsort(kind="mergesort")
    ][:n_neighbours]

    if neighbours.size == 0:
        return 0, np.array([0.0, 0.0])

    velocities = velocities[neighbours]
    weights = weights[neighbours] if weights.size != 0 else None
    average_velocity: npt.NDArray[np.float32] = np.average(
        velocities, weights=weights, axis=0
    )
    return len(neighbours), average_velocity
```

that I need to call many times inside of a for loop

```
for point in my_points:
    average_over_neighbours(distances, velocities)
```

This results in a very slow performance.
I am wondering if there is something particularly slow in this specific function, or if the issue is just the fact that I am calling it many (thousands of) times.
Given the function overhead in python, would rewriting the function such that the loop is inside the function rather than calling it multiple time give a considerable improvement? I tried to do this quickly but did not see a big difference.
I am a bit hesitant to do so, because I am worried it would impact the clarity of the code, but I can't think of other solutions.

Comment: You should look into running your code with a profiler https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html, then you'll see where the most time is used to focus. In general this seems like a problem with exponential complexity, but you could probably parallelize it fairly easily.

Comment: Many informations are missing. We do not know the shapes of the input arrays, which line of the code is slow (as pointed out by user9794), what are the timing (what is "very slow" for you?). Besides `average_over_neighbours` is repeated `my_points` times but `point` is not used so the loop is useless. I guess this is not what you run but a minimal reproducible example would solve all of this (at least a much better example).

Comment: You are both right. Point is used in the loop but it is hard to write a mwe because it comes from a complex piece of code.. I realise it doesn't make much sense in a question phrased this way, sorry.. I think I will have to look into profiling then